# Algorithm to find occurence of subsequence with the least number of breaks

Tags: algorithm, substring, sequence

Given a query (subsequence) and a string (sequence) I'd like to know the minimal number of groups of consecutive characters (or the number of breaks between them) in the string that, when added together, produce the query. The order of characters matters: `abc` does not occur in `cba`.

Example 1: Given the query `abcjkl` and the string `a_b_c_abc_j_k_l_jkl` I'd like the algorithm to find an occurence of `abc` and then of `jkl` — that makes 2 groups. It should prefer the set of groups (`abc` `jkl`) over, say, (`a` `b` `c` `jkl`), since it has less breaks. I don't care about the number of characters between `abc` and `jkl` in the string, it still counts as 1 break.

Example 2: Given the query `abcjkl` and the string `abc_jkl_abcj_kl` I'd also like the algorithm to find 2 groups. I don't really care which set it picks — (`abc` `jkl`) or (`abcj` `kl`).

Comment: Thinking out loud, the first step is to find the first occurrence (if any) of each of the prefix strings: `a`, `ab`, `abc`, `abcj`, `abcjk`. Which is to say (for example) that if the string contains multiple copies of `ab`, you only need to consider the first `ab` in the string. So I'd use a slightly modified [KMP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth–Morris–Pratt_algorithm) that searches for the query string while keeping track of where the prefixes were found.

Comment: Another observation: if you find the prefix `abc` at some position `M`, and the prefix `abcj` at position `N`, then you only need to search for `jkl` between `M` and `N`.

Comment: Meaning, I can forget about `abc` if I don't find `jkl` between `M` and `N`? Not really. For example in `abc_jk_abcj_l` I can only find `jk` between `M` and `N` but it's still required to form the whole subsequence - (`abc` `jk` `l`).

Comment: I envisioned this as a recursive process. So while searching for `jkl` between `M` and `N`, you keep track of the first occurrence of each prefix string: `j` and `jk`. So in your example, the first pass finds `abc`and `abcj`. The second pass finds `jk` between `abc` and `abcj`. And it finds no prefix strings after `abcj`, so `abcj` is dropped. The third pass searches from `jk` to the end of the string to find the 'l'.